# Homology of $S^n - S^k\vee S^\ell$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

Does anyone know a good trick to computing homology groups of the sphere minus the wedge of two spheres of possibly different dimension $S^n \setminus S^k\vee S^\ell$ ? Any particular $k$ and $\ell$ is not so bad, but the general case has so many cases. Can one avoid this with a some sneaky exact sequence?

Comment: You can use Alexander Duality. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexander_duality

Comment: Thank you @GrumpyParsnip! That's even easier than I hoped for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Grumpy Parsnip suggests we can take Alexander duality so that

\begin{align*}
\tilde H_i(S^n - S^k \vee S^\ell; \mathbb Z) &\cong \tilde H^{n-i-1}(S^k \vee S^\ell; \mathbb Z)\end{align*}
which is $\mathbb Z$ for $i=n-1-k$ or $n-1-\ell$ and trivial otherwise.